# Renaming column does not allow to use it in batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do some updates and rename a column if it has old name, so am trying to do like this:

```
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'NewColumn' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'Potatoes'))
BEGIN
    UPDATE Potatoes SET OldColumn = 4 WHERE SomeColumn = 1
    EXEC SP_RENAME 'dbo.Potatoes.OldColumn', 'NewColumn', 'COLUMN';     
END
GO
```

Script works fine first time, but while run again enterpreter can't find column named `OldColumn` and returns error. How can I use a column and rename it in a single batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dynamic SQL will fix your problem:

```
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'NewColumn' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'Potatoes'))
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE Potatoes SET OldColumn = 4 WHERE SomeColumn = 1';
    EXEC SP_RENAME 'dbo.Potatoes.OldColumn', 'NewColumn', 'COLUMN';     
END
GO
```

This a compile-time issue, because the `UPDATE` gets an unknown column error during the compilation phase of the batch.

Comment: Yep, running string is a way if no other found. I even thought about `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Also, just `EXEC '...'` will lead to incorrect syntax error

Comment: @FLCL . . . Ahh, those parentheses, sigh.